# {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."} In Umbraco 7.2.6

Tags: umbraco

When I set site's Culture and Host names, I got the following Error Message in  **Umbraco 7.2.6**.

**{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}**

Please give a solution for this issue.

Comment: Is user you use to set culture and hostname admin or in any other role?

Comment: looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022859/umbraco-7-2-6-installation-and-cultural-and-host-name-issues

Comment: I am using ADMIN role. Do you  have any idea..   Look this link . I'm posted the same question with screen shots in Umbraco Forum.........https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7//66826-authorization-has-been-denied-for-this-request-error

Comment: I have not faced this issue, but this message appears when there is request to a controller of type `UmbracoAuthorizedJsonController` and requestor is not authenticated. In your case its coming from built in umbraco implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this error myself.

My problem was having registered the webapi route manually like this in my OWIN startup.

```
// register default api route
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Apparently this will cause umbraco to behave the way described above.

My solution was to remove the owin registration and cave in and conform to the setup recommended by umbraco: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/

And there by changing my api urls from

```
mysite.com/api/products/all
```

to

```
mysite.com/umbraco/api/products/all
```