# Umbraco 7.2.6 Installation and Cultural and Host Name Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco, umbraco7

I am developing a web application using  MVC 4, WebAPI 2.0 and Umbraco 7.2.6. Today I was faced two issues

**Issue 1**

**Cultural and Host Name**:Unable to save culture and hostname. Please see the  attached screenshot. [image]

---

[image]

**Issue 2**

While creating new Umbraco installation, I got this error

> "Cannot create an MVC Area path without the umbracoPath specified"

. I fixed this issue by adding . after That i am getting errors one by one. The latest error I got is `"System.Web.WebPages.Razor"` doesnot exists but I checked the path by taking properties and I can find the dll in the path.

Can some one help to fix this issue?

Comment: Re issue 2, have you checked this out? https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/40574-Cannot-create-an-MVC-Area-path-without-the-umbracoPath-specified

Comment: Did it help? :-) I'm now thinking it could fix both problems, actually.

Comment: @JannikAnker No, I got the second issue fixed.

Comment: Re issue 1, maybe this'll do it? https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/48446-cannot-update-culture-and-host-names

Comment: @JannikAnker Can you please explain how to fix. I saw another is person having the same issue. Do we need to make the change directly in table is that the fix? Regarding "clientIDMode" change, my web.config doesnot have this field.

Comment: I don't know how to fix it, I'm trying to help you find a solution! I don't have this problem myself. If you create another new installation, are you seeing the same issues? Are you installing via Nuget? Seems like some people have issues like these if their web.config hasn't been updated correctly.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Yes I used Nuget to install umbraco in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today. When I used a clean install of 7.2.6 it worked fine, so I compared the api call of my Umbraco with the clean one and noticed that mine was pointing at /api/v1/DomainsApi/SaveLanguageAndDomains instead of /umbraco/BackOffice/Api/DomainsApi/SaveLanguageAndDomains.

It turned out that this was caused by my own call to MapHttpRoute where I register my own api. Once I removed it the error was gone.

I have no idea yet why this causes the internal api of Umbraco to use a different path. The only thing I can imagine is that it uses the first mapped http route which now had become mine. Changing the route name did not help...

Unfortunately I don't have a real solution yet and would still like to use my own api routes.